# Copy a file into a directory with its original leading directories appended

Tags: python, python-3.x, copy, shutil

I wonder if python provides a canonical way to copy a file to a directory with its original leading directories appended, like `cp --parents` does. From `cp` man page :

```
`--parents'
[...]
     cp --parents a/b/c existing_dir

 copies the file `a/b/c' to `existing_dir/a/b/c', creating any
 missing intermediate directories.
```

I haven't seen anything in `shutil` documentation that refers to this. Of course, I could create the whole directory structure in `existing_dir` directory before copying any file to it, but it is perhaps overhead to do this.

Comment: I think this is the kind of stuff you program yourself of find a library that have this feature. It depends on relative paths while the things on `shutil` shouldn't

Comment: Look at the docs for 'os' -- it sounds like you want to emulate a 'mkdir -p' for the path, and then copy a file into it?

Comment: @JonathanVanasco: yes, that's it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally came up with the following code. It acts almost exactly as `cp --parents` does.

```
import os, shutil

def cp_parents(target_dir, files):
    dirs = []
    for file in files:
        dirs.append(os.path.dirname(file))
    dirs.sort(reverse=True)
    for i in range(len(dirs)):
        if not dirs[i] in dirs[i-1]:
            need_dir = os.path.normpath(target_dir + dirs[i])
            print("Creating", need_dir )
            os.makedirs(need_dir)
    for file in files:
        dest = os.path.normpath(target_dir + file)
        print("Copying %s to %s" % (file, dest))
        shutil.copy(file, dest)
```

Call it like this:

```
target_dir = '/tmp/dummy'
files = [ '/tmp/dir/file1', '/tmp/dir/subdir/file2', '/tmp/file3' ]

cp_parents(target_dir, files)
```

Output is:

```
Creating /tmp/dummy/tmp/dir/subdir
Copying /tmp/dir/file1 to /tmp/dummy/tmp/dir/file1
Copying /tmp/dir/subdir/file2 to /tmp/dummy/tmp/dir/subdir/file2
Copying /tmp/file3 to /tmp/dummy/tmp/file3
```

There is probably a better way to handle this, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure on your specific requirements, but sounds like `shutil.copytree` will be right for you. You can see the full docs [here](http://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html), but basically all you need to call in your example is something like

```
shutil.copytree( 'a/b/c', 'existing_dir/a/b/c' )
```

Comment: In fact, `shutil.copytree` copies the entire source tree, while what I want is to only copy some files of it.

Comment: Oh, was sure it only copied files from the directory you specified and deeper EDIT: re-read, misinterpreted c as a directory in my answer, didn't realise you meant for it to be a file

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import shutil

files = [ '/usr/bin/ls','/etc/passwd' , '/var/log/daily.out' , '/var/log/system.log' , '/var/log/asl/StoreData' ]

def copy_structure(dst_dir,source_files):
    if not os.path.exists(dst_dir) and os.path.isdir(dst_dir):
        os.mkdir(dst_dir)
    for file in source_files:
        dir_name = os.path.dirname(file)
        final_dir_path = os.path.normpath(dst_dir+dir_name)
        if not os.path.exists(final_dir_path):
            os.makedirs(final_dir_path)            
        if os.path.exists(file): 
            shutil.copy(file,final_dir_path)

copy_structure('/tmp/backup',files)
```

Answer (score 0):

ONLY 3.6 or higher (it uses f function)

This is my implementation of cp --parents

First gets the offsets for getting the src directories and the filename, also, for the directory offset (sometimes i wanted to omit the first folder of the src file)

Then it extracts the folders and the filename (the check in the src_dirs is because i noticed that when src file wasnt nested in any folder it crashed)

Finally it creates the directory tree into the destination folder and copies the file into it

```
def __copy_parents(src, dest_folder, dir_offset=0):
    ''' Copies src tree into dest, offset (optional) omits n folders of the src path'''
    prev_offset = 0 if dir_offset == 0 else src.replace('/', '%', dir_offset - 1).find('/') + 1
    post_offset = src.rfind('/')

    src_dirs = '' if post_offset == -1 else src[prev_offset:post_offset]
    src_filename = src[post_offset + 1:]

    os.makedirs(f'{dest_folder}/{src_dirs}', exist_ok=True)
    shutil.copy(src, f'{dest_folder}/{src_dirs}/{src_filename}')
```